# Do I need to add anything more to the condition on this CASE WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure if this will work. I would try it myself but currently I can't because I don't have access to the server the data is pulled from. The thing is when for example my third condition is true, the others are too. Do I have to add anything to the conditions to make the previous ones false or will it work and "ignore" the previous ones?

```
CASE WHEN
TO_CHAR(f.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY 
HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN ..... 
WHEN TO_CHAR(f.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') + 2/24 < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-
DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN ..... 
WHEN TO_CHAR(time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') + 4/24 < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-
DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN .....  
END bar
```

Don't mind what comes after THEN.

Comment: don't ever compare dates-as-strings to dates-as-strings, especially if you're going to use a format like `dd mm yyyy ...`; in that system, the string`'10 August 2099'` is counted as before the string `'10 January 1999'`! Moreover, don't convert a date to a string and then try and do date arithmetic on it. Instead, your case expression should be: `case when time + 4/24 < sysdate then ... when time + 2/24 < sysdate then ... when time < sysdate then ... end`

Comment: @Boneist Thank you. I thought I have to do this because I thought the SYSDATE and f.time will only show the DATE and not the TIME. Like I said, I'm a beginner at this stuff

Comment: the DATE (and TIMESTAMP) datatypes in Oracle store both date and time. If they didn't then when you did `to_char(..., '... hh24:mi:ss')`, where did you think the time part was coming from? I wonder if you're confused because when you select the column/sysdate (e.g. in SQL*Plus) you're not seeing the time parts? If so, try running `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` and then rerunning your query. (The nls_date_format is the format mask used when you implicitly convert dates to strings (or vice versa), which defaults to `DD-MON-RR`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder your `WHEN` expressions and start with the least likely (the most restrictive).

```
CASE WHEN
TO_CHAR(time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') + 4/24 < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-
DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN ..... 
WHEN TO_CHAR(f.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') + 2/24 < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-
DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN ..... 
WHEN TO_CHAR(f.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY 
HH24:MI:SS') 
THEN .....  
END bar
```

Documentation for this is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

> In a searched CASE expression, Oracle searches from left to right until it finds an occurrence of condition that is true, and then returns return_expr. If no condition is found to be true, and an ELSE clause exists, Oracle returns else_expr. Otherwise, Oracle returns null.

Comment: Will this change anything? The likeliness of of the expressions will vary a lot

Comment: Yes, it will change something. Oracle is returning the `THEN` expression of **first** `WHEN` statement with condition evaluating to `true`.

Comment: No matter what your conditions are, if you have conditions A and B and you know that `if B happens then A happens as well`, there's no point in checking A and then checking B. Check B: if it's true then A is valid as well; if B is false, then check A.

Comment: If you start with A and it's true, you have no idea if B is true or not, but both results are possible.

Comment: Thank you! Lets say I make it check C first, then B and then A, If for ex. C is false and B is true, will it ignore A?

Comment: Yes, it will stop on B and ignore A.

Answer (score 0):

It will not ignore the previous cases. To tell the truth only the first one will run in your case.
So, yes. You should add some conditions which will make the first two false and leaves just the last one true.

In this case:

```
CASE WHEN 0=1 THEN ...
WHEN 0=2 THEN ...
WHEN 1=1 THEN ...
END
```

Only the third will run.

In this case:

```
 CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN ...
 WHEN 2=2 THEN ...
 WHEN 0=0 THEN ...
 END
```

Only the first will run.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea what kind of conditions I should put there?